# Using Multithreading in django Freezes the site

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am making a Django site in which I have to Upload an image and after Upload, in the background, I am doing some processing on the image in which I am using `Threading` and it successfully works also because previously after uploading the image POST Request used to take 10-20 seconds but now it just happens in a fraction of second and all that processing happens in background but the problem is when that processing happens in the background... Django does not take any NEW HTTPRespone meaning if I wish to go on to some other link it just rotates and rotates until that thread's work is complete, Here's my code:

```
def upload(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        img = requests.FILES['image']
        img_uploader = Image(image=img)
        img_uploader.save()
        image_link = str(img_uploader.image).split("/")[-1]
        start_threading_work(image_link, img_uploader.image_id) # code of this function is below
        print("UPLOAD FUNCTION OVER")

    return redirect('/') # it successfully redirects

def start_threading_work(image_link, image_id):
    keyword_thread = threading.Thread(target=image_keyword_generator, args=(image_link, image_id), daemon=True)
    keyword_thread.start()
    encoding_thread = threading.Thread(target=ImageEncoding, args=(image_link, image_id), daemon=True)
    encoding_thread.start()
```

As you can see the third last line of the upload function which is `start_threading_work(__, __)` it starts the thread and also redirects me. But it refrains to load any new page till the Thread's work is over so what's the point of using threading if I have to wait in either of the cases! So is their any solution or I am making some sort of mistake here.

For more Information you can see code of my entire website here: https://github.com/pritishmishra703/AwesomeImage

Thank you

Comment: Use Celery for background tasks, don't use Threading. They integrare very well.

Comment: Don't use threads in web applications. They tend to block on the development server and might be "recycled" at any time by the WSGI server in a production server. If you have long running task use something like Celery.

Comment: @EneP can you tell me how can I use it? or any resources or useful links are highly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html